# How to print response Json data in jsx

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

[image]

I want to render title and description in jsx (Reside in data-->feed->title or Description)
also want to render each title and each pub date (Reside in data->items[array]->title and pub date)

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';

function Dashboard(){
    const[posts,setPosts] = useState([])

    useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get('https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=http%3A%2F%2Frss.cnn.com%2Fservices%2Fpodcasting%2Fstudentnews%2Frss.xml')
        .then(res=> {
            console.log(res)
            setPosts(res.data) 
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            console.log(err)
        })
    },[])
    return(
        <div className="App">
            
        </div>  
        
       )
}
```

Comment: Hi, please share your API response structure

Comment: Bala, try putting the JSON response as code. stop putting photos. you are just making it that much harder for people to help you by providing insufficient information.

Comment: also, it looks like you are doing JSON in JSX for the first time. Why would you start with something so complex? start with a local json data file and then upgrade to something complex like this. running before walking, eh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you are trying to do something like this ?

```
return(
    <div className="App">

        <div> {posts.feed && posts.feed.title} </div>
        <div> {posts.feed && posts.feed.description} </div>


        <div>
            {posts.items &&  posts.items.map ( postItem => <div> {postItem.title} </div> ) } 
        </div>
        
    </div>  
    
   )
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad, If i try ur code its throwing error as TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Comment: Then you have to provide the exact response model you get from your api. Can you provide one ?

Comment: Hi Mohammad I shared the API response

Comment: Hi Mohammad, Its working for title and description but for items title and pubdate its showing Iike below
postItem.title
postItem.title
postItem.title
postItem.title

Comment: sorry there was a mistake check now

Answer (score 0):

So first of all I suggest you to make your screens class components, than you can make your child components as functional components like above. So you can make a async function that make a request and fetches the data to the state.

Why you getting cannot read property of "title"?
Becouse when you load your component It's instantly looking for your posts array. Which is empty at the begining It need some time to make request and fill your array with the recieved data, that's why you getting this error I believe.
So just try it like following

```
{posts.length && post.map .... .... ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like :

```
return(
    <div className="App">
    { 
     
        (posts.items!==undefined && posts.items.length>0) && posts.items.map ( ele=> {
                        return (<div>{ele.title} - {ele.pubDate} </div> )}) 
     
    }
        
    </div>  
    
   )
```

Comment: Hi Priyanks,  I shared my API response

Comment: Hi Priyanka,  For above code its throwing TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined